# Square-shaped button Android

Tags: android-button

I want a layout of square-sized buttons with just 2 columns, pretty much like Windows Phone 7 start screen.

However, I do not want to make my own custom button, use libraries or use fixed values (as this would end up with density inconsistencies). I just want to achieve this using styles and XML, and I want the solution to be density-independant.

I've seen an app (Apollo) that achieves this, but I don't know how.

Is there any way to do this or am I forced to override onMeasure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the height and width of the button according to the screen size you can do this in your activity.

```
 WindowManager w = getWindowManager(); 
 Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int sw = d.getWidth(); //Gives the screen width and height
        int sh = d.getHeight();
```

The use this to set the height and width of the button. Use the layout in which the button is contained. Here I have used Linear Layout as an example.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = sw-padding;
params.heigth=sh;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I know all of this. I just want a button whose width is equal to half of the screen minus padding and its height is equal to its width. Nothing of your answer gives me this.